# Cascade cocoa bindings

Tags: cocoa, binding, cascade

I'm trying to cascade the enabled value for some checkboxes.
I have 3 checkboxes
()1
  ()2
    ()3

I want the checkbox 2 and 3 disabled when checkbox 1 is unchecked.
When checkbox 1 is checked checkbox 2 should be enabled. Checkbox 3 should only be enabled if checkbox 1 AND 2 is checked.

Is it possible to cascade these bindings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally best not to think about or try binding *to* view properties. For one thing, they are often not KVO-compliant.

Rather, bind each checkbox's `value` binding to a property on the controller. Then, bind the `enabled` bindings to those same properties on the controller.

**Checkbox 1:**
Value binding
Bind to: your controller
Model key path: property1

**Checkbox 2:**
Value binding
Bind to: your controller
Model key path: property2

Enabled binding
Bind to: your controller
Model key path: property1

**Checkbox 3:**
Enabled binding
Bind to: your controller
Model key path: property1

Enabled2 binding
Bind to: your controller
Model key path: property2